# invalid date in firefox converting string to date(mm-dd-yyyy) in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, firefox

hi i am getting a string in form of mm-dd-yyyy so i am converting it into date object using new date() which is working fine in IE , Chrome but not working in FF it returns invalid date some time i tried rejx also

```
var admiDatePD = new Date( document.getElementById("ADMISSIONDATE-PD0").value.replace(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*$/, '$2/$3/$1') );
            alert(admiDatePD);
            var disDatePD = new Date( document.getElementById("DISCHARGEDATE-PD0").value.replace(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*$/, '$2/$3/$1') );
            alert(disDatePD);
```

please help to solve this problem.

Comment: hey jeffman thanks for reply well i just debug it i watch 
document.getElementById("ADMISSIONDATE-PD0").value.replace(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*$/, '$2/$3/$1')
 "11-19-2013" and i am geting that string when i put in new date() it show invalid date

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the order of your string is wrong. The string for new date should be in a compliant format as explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. so in your case, converting to "2012-03-20" YYYY-MM-DD works.